# Cannot center table cell content with scrollable cells

Tags: html, css

I have a table with some cells with enough text content that they need to be scrollable and some cells that have content only taking up one line of text.  The problem is, I need to use a div for my use case and can't seem to center the text vertically while keeping the scrollable cells working as intended.

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
th{
    border: black 5px solid;
}

th div{
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}

th div p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Autem a rerum alias labore, sed dolorum
                        at debitis sint tenetur velit fugit officiis id eos provident quae ipsum ea? Doloremque,
                        quaerat?</p>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

in the div, but that makes the top portion of the scrollable div to be hidden above the top of the cell...

How can I alter my CSS to uniformly allow single line cells to be centered vertically, but scrollable cells to work the way they do now?

Comment: Trying the runnable example above, I'm not following what the issue seems to be? Looks ok to me.

Comment: @PaulT. So, the lorem ipsum in the right cell is at the top of the cell. I want it to be centered vertically, but when I try doing that, it cuts off the top of the content in my left cell

Comment: try div {height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }

Comment: the duplicate I gave in your old question aready gives you the reason and the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With you existing css and html, just try adding this:

```
th div {
    display: flex;
}

th div p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will work!
And if you don't want your text to be horizontally centered:

```
th div p {
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

```css
th{
    border: black 5px solid;
}

th div{
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    display: flex;
}

th div p{
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Autem a rerum alias labore, sed dolorum
                        at debitis sint tenetur velit fugit officiis id eos provident quae ipsum ea? Doloremque,
                        quaerat?</p>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use max-height instead height

```
th div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 125px;
    max-height: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this CSS code.

```
th div p {
  max-height: 115px;
}

div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Best regards.